# Return AS3.0 Int value

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, return, int

I am trying to return an int value from actionscript inside a symbol.

This is the code inside of the symbol/movieclip.

```
function flytt():void{
   var flyttInMb:int=Math.random() * 8;
   if(flyttInMb==0){
      x=243,30;
      y=171,65;
   }
}
```

This is the code I have tried for returning the flyttInMb to the actionscript that is the game, instead of inside one of the symbols, and what I get is this: Return value must be undefined.
Any way I can return the flyttInMb out of the symbol, onto my actionscript?

This is how I try to call the flyttInK and the flyttInMb:

```
if(flyttInK==flyttInMb){
   Kone.flytt();
   Baby.flytt();
}
```

The thing is.. I want to keep the flyttInMb value, so that I can move the Kone and the baby if their number is the same, so no mole ever appears on the same spot.

Comment: Hi could you format your code please? Use the {} buttons to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try this to get a return value from a method:

```
function returnValue():uint
{
  return Math.round(Math.random()*8);
};
```

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for adding a new answer, but I feel like it is better this way.

In order to be able to return anything from a method you have to actually set it in the method declaration and you have to return a value in the method. See below:

**In the movie clip symbols**

```
function flytt():uint
{
   var flyttInMb:uint = Math.round(Math.random() * 8);

   if(flyttInMb == 0)
   {
      x=243.30; //Use full stop instead if comma!
      y=171.65; //Use full stop instead if comma!
   }

   return flyttInMb;
};
```

In the method declaration I say I will return a `uint` value and the last line of the method returns the generated random number.

**In your main script**

To be honest I don't understand what you are trying to do with this:

```
if(flyttInK==flyttInMb){
   Kone.flytt();
   Baby.flytt();
}
```

- what is `flyttInk`?
- what is `flyttInMb` - it has got the same name as the generated value in the symbol script.
- The Kone.flytt(); and Baby.flytt(); calls seem to be static class method calls which won't return anything in this context. Try to call the actual instantiated items' methods which would be something like this:

var kone:Kone = new Kone();
...
var returnValueOfKoneInstance:uint = kone.flytt();

I hope you get closer with this,

Rob